# Is there a way to get DataFrame column index numbers based on what's in the header?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a Dataframe that contains columns that have 'X' above them in the header, but I'm unable to find a way to get column index numbers.

I would select the right dataframe once I have the column index numbers.

```
df_right_columns = df_right_column[df_right_column.columns[column_numbers]]
```

Sample df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['column1', 'cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4'],
                   'X': ['column2', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 6'],
                   '': ['column3', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 7'],
                   'X': ['column4', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 6', 'cell 8']})


   X      X                X
column1 column2 column3 column4
cell 1  cell 2  cell 3  cell 4
cell 2  cell 3  cell 4  cell 5
cell 3  cell 4  cell 5  cell 6
cell 4  cell 5  cell 6  cell 7
cell 5  cell 6  cell 7  cell 8
```

I have tried running this dataframe through for loop to try get the index numbers but haven't had any luck so far. I did this by 1) locating the X header row, 2) running this row through for loop to check columns that contain 'X' in the df.iloc[0] row.

```
df = df.iloc[0]

for cell in df:
   if 'X' in cell:
     print(cell.index)   #this will return an object - <built-in method index of str object at 0x7f23be18a9b0>      
     print(cell) #this will return the cell value not the index, X in this case
```

I'm very close and any help would be grealty appreciated, many thanks

**Solution**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['column1', 'cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4'],
               'X': ['column2', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 6'],
               '': ['column3', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 7'],
               'X': ['column4', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 6', 'cell 8']})

print(df)

   X      X                X
column1 column2 column3 column4
cell 1  cell 2  cell 3  cell 4
cell 2  cell 3  cell 4  cell 5
cell 3  cell 4  cell 5  cell 6
cell 4  cell 5  cell 6  cell 7
cell 5  cell 6  cell 7  cell 8

df_header = df.iloc[0]

column_number = []
i = 0
while i < len(df_header):
  for column_index in df_header:
    if 'X' in column_index:
      column_number.append(i)
    i += 1

df = df[df.columns[column_number]]

print(df)

   X       X        X
column1 column2  column4
cell 1  cell 2    cell 4
cell 2  cell 3    cell 5
cell 3  cell 4    cell 6
cell 4  cell 5    cell 7
cell 5  cell 6    cell 8
```

Comment: Can you please share the code to instantiate the input dataframe? Have the correct index/columns is kinda important for this question.

Comment: It's initiated from a spreadsheet, but let me try get you the code

Comment: I have added the input df code @timgeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a MultiIndex:

```
Xs = ['X', 'X', None, 'X']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Xs, df.columns])
```

or, from a list of positions:

```
pos = (0,1,3)
Xs = ['X' if i in pos else '' for i in range(len(df.columns))]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Xs, df.columns])
```

output:

```
        X       X     NaN       X
  column1 column2 column3 column4
0  cell 1  cell 2  cell 3  cell 4
1  cell 2  cell 3  cell 4  cell 5
2  cell 3  cell 4  cell 5  cell 6
3  cell 4  cell 5  cell 6  cell 7
4  cell 5  cell 6  cell 7  cell 8
```

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5'],
                   'column2': ['cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 6'],
                   'column3': ['cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 6', 'cell 7'],
                   'column4': ['cell 4', 'cell 5', 'cell 6', 'cell 7', 'cell 8']})
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```py
table =  [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
              {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
              {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000}]
    df = pd.DataFrame(table)
    print("total size row: ", df.index.size)
    for value in df.values:
        print("size col: ", value.size, "value:", value)

output:
total size row:  3
size col:  4 value: [1 2 3 4]
size col:  4 value: [100 200 300 400]
size col:  4 value: [1000 2000 3000 4000]
```